# Hierarchy error JQuery insertBefore()

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make an HTML form with a button for adding an input field. I use JQuery to select my objects (elements are placed in a div). When I try to use either `append()` or `insertBefore()` (not sure which one), I get

`Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parent.`

This is my code:

```
<form id = "userForm" action = "/" method = "POST">
      <div name = "userFunction">
        <input type = "radio" name = "function" value = "SUM"/>SUM<br/>
        <input type = "radio" name = "function" value = "AVERAGE"/>AVERAGE
      </div>
      <div name = "userArgs">

      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var numberFuncs = ["SUM", "AVERAGE"];
        var form = $("#userForm");
        var func = form.find("input[name='function']:checked").val();
        var userArgs = form.find("div[name='userArgs']");
        var spanEl = $("<span>Enter a number: </span>");
        var inputEl = $("<input name = 'arg' type = 'number'/>");
        userArgs.append(spanEl);
        userArgs.append(inputEl);
        var buttonEl = $("<button name = 'add' type = 'button' onclick = 'addArg()'>Add an argument field</button>");
        userArgs.append($("<br/>"));
        userArgs.append(buttonEl);
        function addArg(){
        var form = $("#userForm");
         var spanEl = $("<span>Enter a number: </span>");
         var inputEl = $("<input name = 'arg' type = 'number'/>");
         var userArgs = form.find("div[name='userArgs']");
         var buttonEl = userArgs.find($("button[name='add']"));
         console.log(buttonEl.text());
         $("br").insertBefore(buttonEl);
         spanEl.insertBefore(buttonEl);
         userArgs.insertBefore(buttonEl);

        }
      </script>
      <input type = "submit" value = "submit"/>
    </form>
```

Please tell me what exactly I am doing incorrectly. Thanks! (As some of you may know from the code, this is intended to be a Flask application after I solve this issue).

## UPDATE:

I know that the problem is `insertBefore()` because my `console.log(buttonEl.text());` is working (the first line of my Google Chrome JS console is `Add an argument field`. Also, the button disappears (not the submit, but the "add an argument field one") after I click it.

Comment: It looks like `buttonE1` is a child of `userArgs`, and then you are trying to insert `userArgs` before `buttonE1`, so you are trying to insert `userArgs` inside itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`buttonE1` is a child of `userArgs`, and when `addArg()` is called, you are trying to insert `userArgs` before `buttonE1`, so you are trying to insert `userArgs` inside itself.

I think you want to insert the `inputEl` element, not the `userArgs` element. You could also reduce the redundant code by calling the `addArg()` function:

```
var form = $("#userForm");
var userArgs = form.find("div[name='userArgs']");
var $addBtn = $("<button name='add' type='button' onclick='addArg()'>Add an argument field</button>");
userArgs.append($addBtn);

function addArg() {
    $addBtn.before("<span>Enter a number: </span>"
        + "<input name='arg' type='number'/>"
        + "<br/>");
}

addArg();
```

---

Better:

```
var form = $("#userForm");
var userArgs = form.find("div[name='userArgs']");
var $addBtn = $("<button name='add' type='button'>Add an argument field</button>");
userArgs.append($addBtn);

$addBtn.click(function() {
    $addBtn.before("<span>Enter a number: </span>"
        + "<input name='arg' type='number'/>"
        + "<br/>");
}).click();
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I misunderstood the nature of `insertBefore()`. Thank you even more for your shorter code :P. It's much easier to understand

Comment: Your code made my button disappear completely though

Comment: @ytpillai - I think I should have used `.before()` instead of `insertBefore()`. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ah.. That makes a lot more sense. Thanks! I should have seen that ugh it's 1:45 here. I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

I guess you made a typo

```
userArgs.insertBefore(buttonEl); //The problem comes from this line
```

Did you want to add the input instead ?

```
inputEl.insertBefore(buttonEl);
```

Cause when doing 'userArgs.insertBefore(buttonEl);' you try to add userArgs before buttonEl, but buttonEl is itself **inside** userArgs, so you try to nest userArgs (userArgs-Ception... :D )